# SQL Server Convert XML to JSON

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, xml

I would like to convert an XML column into a JSON string. So far I've tried few options on SO and Google, but all of them convert a table into a JSON string. Is there any way I can do this without converting the xml into a table first?

Version: SQL Server 2014 (SP2)

```
declare @xml xml
select @xml = xml_column from mytable
select some_potential_function(@xml) as JSON_String
```

PS: My xml grows dynamically as I store a tree with varying number of levels in it. That's why converting it to a table may not be an option.

Comment: Check this article, fairly illustrated here with decent number of examples -
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/producing-json-documents-from-sql-server-queries-via-tsql/

Comment: I'm actually trying to achieve something exactly what this page offers: http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/#.WFI4wvl96Uk

Answer (score 2):

You might try ".nodes()" method on XML type to do this (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) along with FOR JSON AUTO in SQL Server 2016 and above (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921882.aspx) :

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <catalog>
       <book id="bk101">
          <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
       </book>
       <book id="bk102">
          <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
       </book>
    </catalog>''';
SELECT b.value('@id', 'nvarchar(MAX)') AS book
    ,b.value('author[1]', 'nvarchar(MAX)') AS author
    -- the rest of your columns
FROM @xml.nodes('/catalog/book') AS a(b)
FOR JSON AUTO
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. As I indicated in the question, my SQL Server version is 2014. So this won't be an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this sample for stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @xml_doc [xml] = 
        N'<MyTable>
            <MyRow>
                <PropertyI>abc</PropertyI>
                <PropertyII>987654310</PropertyII>
                <PropertyIII>12:00</PropertyIII>
                <PropertyIV>false</PropertyIV>
                <PropertyV>
                    <PropertyVI>123</PropertyVI>
                    <PropertyVII>456</PropertyVII>
                </PropertyV>
            </MyRow>
            <MyRow>
                <PropertyI>xyz</PropertyI>
                <PropertyII>0123456798</PropertyII>
                <PropertyIII>12:00</PropertyIII>
                <PropertyIV>NULL</PropertyIV>
                <PropertyV />
            </MyRow>
        </MyTable>',
    @json_doc [nvarchar](max) = NULL;

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @doc_handle [int];

    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @doc_handle OUTPUT, @xml_doc;

    DECLARE @base TABLE (
        [id] [bigint],
        [parentid] [bigint],
        [localname] [nvarchar](4000),
        [sub] [nvarchar](max),
        [level] [bigint]);

    DECLARE @sample TABLE (
        [id] [bigint],
        [parentid] [bigint],
        [localname] [nvarchar](4000),
        [sub] [nvarchar](max),
        [level] [bigint]);

    WITH [parsed_xml] AS (
            SELECT [id] AS [id]
                ,[parentid] AS [parentid]
                ,[nodetype] AS [nodetype]
                ,[localname] AS [localname]
                ,[prefix] AS [prefix]
                ,[namespaceuri] AS [namespaceuri]
                ,[datatype] AS [datatype]
                ,[prev] AS [prev]
                ,REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT([nvarchar](max), [text]), CHAR(10), '\n'), CHAR(13), '\n') AS [text]
            FROM OPENXML (@doc_handle, '.', 1))
        ,[cte] AS (
            SELECT [id]
                ,[parentid]
                ,[localname]
            FROM [parsed_xml]
            WHERE [parentid] IS NULL
            UNION ALL
            SELECT [parsed_xml].[id]
                ,[parsed_xml].[parentid]
                ,[parsed_xml].[localname]
            FROM [cte]
                JOIN [parsed_xml]
                    ON [parsed_xml].[parentid] = [cte].[id]
                        AND [parsed_xml].[nodetype] = 1)
        ,[cte_vi] AS (
            SELECT DISTINCT [cte].[parentid]
                ,[cte].[id]
                ,[cte].[localname] AS [localname]
                ,IIF([property].[localname] IS NULL, NULL,
                    CONCAT('"', [property].[localname], '"', ' : '
                        ,CASE
                            WHEN [value].[text] IS NULL THEN 'null'
                            WHEN [value].[text] = 'null' THEN 'null'
                            ELSE CONCAT('"', [value].[text], '"')
                            END)) AS [sub]
            FROM [cte]
                JOIN [parsed_xml] AS [property]
                    ON [property].[parentid] = [cte].[id]
                        AND [property].[nodetype] = 1
                LEFT JOIN [parsed_xml] AS [value]
                    ON [value].[parentid] = [property].[id])
        ,[cte_ii] AS (
            SELECT [id]
                ,[parentid]
                ,[localname]
                ,STRING_AGG([sub], ', ') AS [sub]
            FROM [cte_vi]
            GROUP BY [id]
                ,[parentid]
                ,[localname])
        ,[cte_iii] AS (
            SELECT [id]
                ,[parentid]
                ,[localname]
                ,[sub]
                ,(1) AS [level]
            FROM [cte_ii]
            WHERE [parentid] IS NULL
            UNION ALL
            SELECT [cte_ii].[id]
                ,[cte_ii].[parentid]
                ,[cte_ii].[localname]
                ,[cte_ii].[sub]
                ,[cte_iii].[level] + (1) AS [level]
            FROM [cte_iii]
                JOIN [cte_ii]
                    ON [cte_ii].[parentid] = [cte_iii].[id])
    INSERT INTO @base
    SELECT [id]
        ,[parentid]
        ,[localname]
        ,IIF([sub] IS NULL, NULL, CONCAT('{', [sub], '}')) AS [sub]
        ,[level]
    FROM [cte_iii];

    EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @doc_handle;

    WHILE ((SELECT MAX([level]) FROM @base) > 1)
    BEGIN

        WITH [cte] AS (
                SELECT MAX([level]) AS [max_level]
                FROM @base)
            ,[cte_i] AS (
                SELECT [base].*
                FROM @base AS [base]
                    JOIN [cte]
                        ON [cte].[max_level] = [base].[level])
        INSERT INTO @sample
        SELECT *
        FROM [cte_i];

        WITH [cte] AS (
                SELECT [parentid]
                    ,[localname]
                    ,STRING_AGG([sub], ',') AS [sub]
                FROM @sample
                GROUP BY [parentid]
                    ,[localname])
            ,[cte_i] AS (
                SELECT [parentid]
                    ,[localname]
                    ,IIF([sub] IS NULL, NULL, CONCAT('[', [sub], ']')) AS [sub]
                FROM [cte])
            ,[cte_ii] AS (
                SELECT [id]
                    ,[parentid]
                    ,[localname]
                    ,[sub]
                    ,(1) AS [level]
                FROM @base AS [base]
                WHERE EXISTS (
                    SELECT TOP (1) 'EXISTS'
                    FROM [cte_i]
                    WHERE [parentid] = [base].[id])
                UNION ALL
                SELECT [cte_ii].[id]
                    ,[cte_ii].[parentid]
                    ,[cte_ii].[localname]
                    ,JSON_MODIFY([cte_ii].[sub], CONCAT('strict $.', [cte_i].[localname]), JSON_QUERY([cte_i].[sub])) AS [sub]
                    ,[level] + (1) AS [level]
                FROM [cte_ii]
                    JOIN [cte_i]
                        ON [cte_i].[parentid] = [cte_ii].[id]
                WHERE JSON_MODIFY([cte_ii].[sub], CONCAT('strict $.', [cte_i].[localname]), JSON_QUERY([cte_i].[sub])) != [cte_ii].[sub])
            ,[cte_iii] AS (
                SELECT *
                    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [id] ORDER BY [level] DESC) AS [order]
                FROM [cte_ii])
        UPDATE [base]
        SET [sub] = [cte_iii].[sub]
        FROM @base AS [base]
            JOIN [cte_iii]
                ON [cte_iii].[id] = [base].[id]
                    AND [cte_iii].[order] = 1;

        DELETE [base]
        FROM @base AS [base]
            JOIN @sample AS [sample]
                ON [sample].[id] = [base].[id];

        DELETE FROM @sample;

    END

    SELECT TOP (1) @json_doc = [sub]
    FROM @base;

    SELECT @json_doc;

END
```